# Call both middleware & controller method in a route

Tags: laravel, lumen

In my route file I can call a controller method that way

```
$router->get('users/{id}', 'UserController@read');
```

And I can assign a middleware to a route that way, according to the documentation :

```
$app->get('admin/profile', ['middleware' => 'testMiddleware', function () {
    //
}]);
```

But I don't understand how I can combine both.

I tried this but it didn't work :

```
$router->get('users/{id}', 'UserController@read', ['middleware' => 'testMiddleware']);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$router->get('users/{id}', 'UserController@read')->middleware('testMiddleware');
```

by this way the applied middle-ware will get triggered

Comment: I got this error : Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::middleware()
Maybe this is specific to Laravel and doesn't exist in Lumen?

Comment: Right, its specific to Laravel

Answer (score 0):

I just had to swap parameters to make it work :

```
$router->get('users/{id}', ['middleware' => 'testMiddleware'], 'UserController@read');
```